# how to find a null/undefined value into an object of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

What is the best way to find a null/undefined or empty value in a object containing Json, arrays and any other data type?

One alternative could be with string search but I'm not sure if it is a good practice:

```js
myObject = [{foo: 10, bar: 'NY'}, 123, [null, 11, '', 22], undefined, {baz: 99, quz: undefined}];


function containsInvalidValue(object) {
    myString = JSON.stringify(object);
    console.log(myString);
    let containsNull = myString.search("null"),
    containsUndefined = myString.search("undefined"),
    containsEmpty = myString.search("\"\""),
    containsInvalidValue = containsNull + containsUndefined + containsEmpty;
    if(containsInvalidValue < 0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

console.log(containsInvalidValue(myObject));
```

The first problem of this approach is that the `JSON.stringify()` won't include `undefined` fields into json objects. Therefore, the `JSON.stringify(object)` line returns the following:

```
"[{"foo":10,"bar":"NY"},123,[null,11,"",22],null,{"baz":99}]"
```

it ignored the `quz: undefined` in the json.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hacky, but one option is to use `JSON.stringify` with a function which checks whether the value being stringified is `null` or `undefined`:

```js
const myObject = [{foo: 10, bar: 'NY'}, 123, [null, 11, '', 22], undefined, {baz: 99, quz: undefined}];


function containsInvalidValue(object) {
  let hasNullOrUndef = false;
  JSON.stringify(object, (key, val) => {
    if (val === null || val === undefined) {
      hasNullOrUndef = true;
    }
    return val;
  });
  return hasNullOrUndef;
}

console.log(containsInvalidValue(myObject));
```

Or recursively iterate manually:

```js
const myObject = [{foo: 10, bar: 'NY'}, 123, [null, 11, '', 22], undefined, {baz: 99, quz: undefined}];

const check = (val) => {
  if (val === null || val === undefined) {
    return true;
  }
  if (typeof val !== 'object') {
    return false;
  }
  for (const item of Object.values(val)) {
    if (check(item)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
console.log(check(myObject));
```